# Validating a Barcode in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am a beginner C coder working on a program to validate bar codes. So far I have a code that reads in a 12 digit bar code. However, I am having trouble on attaching the 12 digit input to my functions odd_value and even_value. I need theses values to validate my bar code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 12

int print_values(int* x)   {
printf("\nSTEP 1: Sum of odds times 3 is \n" );
printf("STEP 2: Sum of the even digits is \n");
printf("STEP 3: Total sum is \n" );
printf("STEP 4: Calculated check digit is \n" );
printf("STEP 5: Check digit and last digit \n" );
return 0;
} 

int odd_value()    {
int sum_odd = (x[0] + x[2] + x[4] + x[6] + x[8] + x[10])*3;
return sum_odd;
}

int even_value()   {
int sum_even = (x[1] + x[3] + x[5] + x[7] + x[9] + x[11]);
return sum_even;
}

int fill_array(){
int i;
printf("Enter a barcode to check. Separate digits with a space >\n");  
for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
    if(scanf("%d:", &x[i]) != 1) return 0;
}
return 1; 
}     




int main(){

int bar_code[ARRAY_SIZE];
int i, last_digit, check_digit, odd, even;

if(fill_array(bar_code)) {
printf("\nYou entered the code: ");
for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) printf("%d ", bar_code[i]);
}  else {
  puts("failed to read");
}

odd = odd_value();
even = even_value();
last_digit = odd + even;
if(last_digit == 0)  {
   check_digit = 0;
  }   else  {
      check_digit = 10 - last_digit;
  }

 print_values(bar_code);

if(check_digit == bar_code[ARRAY_SIZE])   {
  printf("Barcode is VALID\n"); 
   } else {   
      printf("Barcode is INVALID\n");
  }

return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I updated my code a little bit but now I am a bit confused. I am still working on it, but there are a few main errors I am getting.

First error: Function 'print_values' line 5: 'x' undeclared (first use in this function) (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once)

Second Error: Function 'main' line 61: Expected expression before 'const'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 12

void print_values(int odd_value(const int* x), int even_value(const int* x), int last_digit)   {
printf("\nSTEP 1: Sum of odds times 3 is %d\n", odd_value(&x) );
printf("STEP 2: Sum of the even digits is %d\n", even_value(&x));
printf("STEP 3: Total sum is %d\n", last_digit); 
printf("STEP 4: Calculated check digit is \n" );
printf("STEP 5: Check digit and last digit \n" );
}

int odd_value(const int* x)    {
 int sum_odd = (x[0] + x[2] + x[4] + x[6] + x[8] + x[10])*3;
 return sum_odd;
}

int even_value(const int* x)   {
int sum_even = (x[1] + x[3] + x[5] + x[7] + x[9] + x[11]);
return sum_even;
}

int fill_array(int* x){
   int i;
   printf("Enter a barcode to check. Separate digits with a space >\n");

for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
    if(scanf("%d:", &x[i]) != 1) return 0;
}
return 1;
}     

int main(){

int bar_code[ARRAY_SIZE];
int i, last_digit, check_digit, odd, even;

if(fill_array(bar_code)) {
printf("\nYou entered the code: ");
for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) printf("%d ", bar_code[i]);
 }  else {
  puts("failed to read");
 }

 odd = odd_value(bar_code);
 even = even_value(bar_code);

last_digit = odd + even;

if(last_digit == 0)  {
 check_digit = 0;
 }   else  {
       check_digit = 10 - last_digit;
 }

 if(check_digit == bar_code[11])   {
   printf("Barcode is VALID\n"); 
   } else {   
      printf("Barcode is INVALID\n");
   }

  print_values(odd_value(const int* x), even_value(const int* x), last_digit);

return 0;
  }
```

**EDIT:**

I believe I have one last question about my code. I need my last_digit to equal the last_digit in the value sum. In my main function I have last_digit = sum, but need to manipulate it to be the last_digit in the value sum. For example, if sum = 72, last_digit will be 2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 12

void print_values(int odd, int even, int sum, int last_digit, int check_digit)   {
   printf("\nSTEP 1: Sum of odds times 3 is %d\n", odd );
   printf("STEP 2: Sum of the even digits is %d\n", even);
   printf("STEP 3: Total sum is %d\n", sum);
   printf("STEP 4: Calculated check digit is %d\n", check_digit);
     if(check_digit == last_digit) {
   printf("STEP 5: Check digit and last digit match\n" );
  } else {
   printf("STEP 5: Check digit and last digit do not match\n");
  }
}

int odd_value(const int* x)    {
   int sum_odd = (x[0] + x[2] + x[4] + x[6] + x[8] + x[10])*3;
   return sum_odd;
}

int even_value(const int* x)   {
   int sum_even = (x[1] + x[3] + x[5] + x[7] + x[9]);
   return sum_even;
}

int fill_array(int* x){
   int i;
   printf("Enter a barcode to check. Separate digits with a space >\n");

   for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
       if(scanf("%d:", &x[i]) != 1) return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}     

int main(){

 int bar_code[ARRAY_SIZE];
 int i, last_digit, check_digit, odd, even;

 if(fill_array(bar_code)) {
    printf("\nYou entered the code: ");
    for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) printf("%d ", bar_code[i]);
 }  else {
      puts("failed to read");
 }

 odd = odd_value(bar_code);
 even = even_value(bar_code);

 int sum = odd + even;
 last_digit = sum;

 if(last_digit == 0)  {
    check_digit = 0;
    }   else  {
          check_digit = 10 - last_digit;
    }

 print_values(odd, even, sum, last_digit, check_digit);

 if(check_digit == last_digit)   {
    printf("Barcode is VALID\n"); 
    } else {   
        printf("Barcode is INVALID\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not access `bar_code[ARRAY_SIZE]`, which is out-of-range in `if(check_digit == bar_code[ARRAY_SIZE])` (and of course do not make new code to access out-of-range in anywhere in your code)

Comment: You should be getting lots of errors for that code. Start from the first error, read it, try to understand it, and then fix it. Re-build, and continue with the next first error you get. Continue until you have no errors left. And if you're asking for help about the errors, then *show us* the errors. Copy-paste them verbatim into the body of the question, complete, in full and unedited. Also include informational notes. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: where is `x` defined? You pass the `bar_code` array to the `fill_array` function, but the `fill_array` definition doesn't have any arguments. If you want the `odd_value`, `even_value`, and `fill_array` functions to operate on `bar_code`, you must pass `bar_code` as an argument to those functions or make it global (as @MikeCAT points out, this would not be good practice).

Comment: @yano But making unnecessary global variable is not considered as good.

Comment: for ease of understanding and readability by us humans: 1) indent consistently.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: when this line is executed: `puts("failed to read");`, why is the code continuing to process the barcode[] array when not all the bar code was read?  Suggest following that line with: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`.  Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are found in stdlib.h

Answer (score 0):

Create an argument to pass the (pointer to the first element of) array and use it.

```
int odd_value(const int *x) {
    int sum_odd = (x[0] + x[2] + x[4] + x[6] + x[8] + x[10])*3;
    return sum_odd;
}

int even_value(const int *x) {
    int sum_even = (x[1] + x[3] + x[5] + x[7] + x[9] + x[11]);
    return sum_even;
}
```

Calling them should be like this:

```
odd = odd_value(bar_code);
even = even_value(bar_code);
```

Note that your definition of `fill_array()` is also wrong and the first line of it should be `int fill_array(int *x){`.

**UPDATE:** For the new code:

- define `x` in `print_values()`, or you cannot use it in the function.
- Your arguments for calling `print_values()` is invalid. Write just function name (identifier) to pass function pointers.

I also corrected arguments for `odd_value()` and `even_value()` in `print_values()` to have them suit for added `x`.

improved code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 12

void print_values(const int *x, int odd_value(const int* x), int even_value(const int* x), int last_digit) {
    printf("\nSTEP 1: Sum of odds times 3 is %d\n", odd_value(x));
    printf("STEP 2: Sum of the even digits is %d\n", even_value(x));
    printf("STEP 3: Total sum is %d\n", last_digit); 
    printf("STEP 4: Calculated check digit is \n" );
    printf("STEP 5: Check digit and last digit \n" );
}

int odd_value(const int* x) {
    int sum_odd = (x[0] + x[2] + x[4] + x[6] + x[8] + x[10])*3;
    return sum_odd;
}

int even_value(const int* x) {
    int sum_even = (x[1] + x[3] + x[5] + x[7] + x[9] + x[11]);
    return sum_even;
}

int fill_array(int* x){
    int i;
    printf("Enter a barcode to check. Separate digits with a space >\n");

    for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        if(scanf("%d:", &x[i]) != 1) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void){

    int bar_code[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int i, last_digit, check_digit, odd, even;

    if(fill_array(bar_code)) {
        printf("\nYou entered the code: ");
        for(i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) printf("%d ", bar_code[i]);
    }  else {
        puts("failed to read");
    }

    odd = odd_value(bar_code);
    even = even_value(bar_code);

    last_digit = odd + even;

    if(last_digit == 0)  {
        check_digit = 0;
    } else  {
        check_digit = 10 - last_digit;
    }

    if(check_digit == bar_code[ARRAY_SIZE - 1]) {
        printf("Barcode is VALID\n");
    } else {
        printf("Barcode is INVALID\n");
    }

    print_values(bar_code, odd_value, even_value, last_digit);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you. Also, how could I pass in my sum_even, sum_odd, last_digit values into my print values function? I need to print them in the STEP 1 to STEP 5 part of that function.

Comment: Create arguments that stand for what the function wants.

Comment: So would        int print_values(int* x, int odd_value(const int*x), int even_value(const int*x))   {      work?

Comment: It should work if `intx` is corrected to `int *x`, but not a usual way. Use your function pointers to retrieve the values. By the way, `last_digit` should also be passed, shouldn't it?

Comment: I added last_digit too, I am getting a few errors that I edited my page to show. Also, when you said correcting intx to int *x  isn't a usual way to make it work, what did you mean??

Comment: I think you should pass the calculated values, not the function pointers.

Comment: Can I pass in values that were calculated in my main function? For example, print_values(int odd, int even, int last_digit, int check_digit){